# Do class instances persist in the background?

Tags: python, class

If I have the following code:

```
class derp:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
x = derp(1)
x = derp(2)
```

Will the instance that had the number attribute of 1 be replaced or will it persist?

Comment: Derp, yes it will (in this case)

Comment: Any particular reason you're asking this? If you think you need objects to "persist in the background", the context is going to be very important for determining what you should actually do.

Comment: Or, more generally, if you care about this for any reason other than memory consumption, then you need more information than "Python has a garbage collector".

Comment: I wanted to make sure that x = derp(2) will not leave an instance of derp.

Answer (score 0):

It will eventually be garbage-collected.